# mysql query most recent record

Tags: mysql

I want to create a table in mysql the table has 3 columns user_id,activity - online or offline - and timestamp,
Now I want the table to show all user_id's along with most recent status. Currently using

```
 SELECT DISTINCT user_id,activity FROM activity ORDER BY timestamp DESC
```

statement shows when the user was last online and offline which is not what I want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
 select act.*
 from activity as act
      inner join (
          select user_id, max(timestamp) as max_ts
          from activity
          group by user_id) as a on act.user_id=a.user_Id and act.timestamp=a.max_ts
```

This will return the most recent record for each user.

Comment: @user1712552 sorry about the typo... but it's easy to correct... simply replace it with `user_id`. I'm correcting it now

Answer (score 1):

```
select user_id, max(timestamp) ts from activity a
inner join
   (select user_id, activity, max(timestamp) ts
   group by user_id, activity) iam
on iam.user_id =a.user_id and a.ts = iam.ts
```

Comment: OP wants offline record if that is later than online